# Is PoE 802.3af Compatible with 802.3at?

Tags: networking, ethernet, power-over-ethernet

If I connect a device that is compliant with POE 802.3af (surveillance camera) to a device (switch) which is POE 802.3at. It will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​